How to make Huawei E5372 USB 4g LTE Modem work on Debian 12?
I'm trying to make my Huawei E5372 USB modem work with my Debian 12 Linux with Gnome Desktop Environment but having no luck with it.
When listing modems with ModemManager the USB modem is shown:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1 [huawei] E5372

When listing the USB Modem info with ModemManager the following is shown:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -m 1
  --------------------------------
  General  |                 path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1
           |            device id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: huawei
           |                model: E5372
           |    firmware revision: 21.221.19.00.00
           |            supported: gsm-umts
           |              current: gsm-umts
           |         equipment id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1
           |              drivers: huawei_cdc_ncm, option
           |               plugin: huawei
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (at), ttyUSB0 (at), wwx0c5b8f279a64 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Status   |       unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-puk (10), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk2 (10)
           |                state: registered
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 100% (recent)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                       allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none
           |              current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
           |          operator id: 72404
           |        operator name: TIMBRASIL
           |         registration: home
           | packet service state: attached
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-2
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |     primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/1
  --------------------------------
  Bearer   |                paths: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/4
           |                       /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/3
           |                       /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/2


ModemManager bearer info are:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -m 1 -b 2
  --------------------------------------
  General    |                     path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/2
             |                     type: default
  --------------------------------------
  Status     |                connected: no
             |    connection error name: org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported
             | connection error message: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
             |                suspended: no
             |              multiplexed: no
             |               ip timeout: 20
  --------------------------------------
  Properties |                      apn: timbrasil.br
             |                  roaming: allowed
             |                  ip type: ipv4v6
             |                     user: tim
             |                 password: tim
  --------------------------------------
  Statistics |                 attempts: 8
             |                 attempts: 8

tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -m 1 -b 3
  --------------------------------------
  General    |                     path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/3
             |                     type: default
  --------------------------------------
  Status     |                connected: no
             |    connection error name: org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.MobileEquipment.Unknown
             | connection error message: Unknown error
             |                suspended: no
             |              multiplexed: no
             |               ip timeout: 20
  --------------------------------------
  Properties |                      apn: timbrasil.br
             |                  roaming: allowed
             |                  ip type: ipv4
             |                     user: tim
             |                 password: tim
  --------------------------------------
  Statistics |                 attempts: 8
             |                 attempts: 8

tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -m 1 -b 4
  --------------------------------------
  General    |                     path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/4
             |                     type: default
  --------------------------------------
  Status     |                connected: no
             |    connection error name: org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported
             | connection error message: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
             |                suspended: no
             |              multiplexed: no
             |               ip timeout: 20
  --------------------------------------
  Properties |                      apn: timbrasil.br
             |                  roaming: allowed
             |                  ip type: ipv6
             |                     user: tim
             |                 password: tim
  --------------------------------------
  Statistics |                 attempts: 8
             |                 attempts: 8


ModemManager Interface info is:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo mmcli -i 1
  -------------------------------
  General    |              path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/1
  -------------------------------
  Properties |            active: yes
             |              imsi: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
             |             iccid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
             |       operator id: 72404
             |     operator name: TIM
             |              gid2: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF


The huawei-4g NetworkManager connection is configured as following:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo nmcli c show huawei-4g | cat
connection.id:                          huawei-4g
connection.uuid:                        0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        gsm
connection.interface-name:              cdc-wdm0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1726645128
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.mptcp-flags:                 0x0 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
connection.wait-activation-delay:       -1
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.link-local:                        0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv4.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     default
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.mtu:                               auto
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.token:                             --
gsm.auto-config:                        no
gsm.number:                             --
gsm.username:                           tim
gsm.password:                           <hidden>
gsm.password-flags:                     0 (none)
gsm.apn:                                "timbrasil.br"
gsm.network-id:                         --
gsm.pin:                                <hidden>
gsm.pin-flags:                          0 (none)
gsm.home-only:                          no
gsm.device-id:                          --
gsm.sim-id:                             --
gsm.sim-operator-id:                    --
gsm.mtu:                                auto
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --

When trying to connect to it, the following error is shown:
tiago@dell-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo nmcli c up huawei-4g
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown error
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e + NM_DEVICE=cdc-wdm0' to get more details.


The syslog shows the following:
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6054] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'huawei-4g' (0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e)
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6055] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6063] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6075] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6271] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to connect modem: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6272] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6278] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'huawei-4g'
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6280] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6286] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'huawei-4g' (0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e)
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6287] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6290] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6297] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6469] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to connect modem: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6469] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6473] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'huawei-4g'
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6475] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6481] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'huawei-4g' (0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e)
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6482] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6487] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6495] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6663] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to connect modem: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6663] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6665] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'huawei-4g'
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6666] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6669] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: starting connection 'huawei-4g' (0aa9ce26-96a3-49a8-a509-f48e56a3981e)
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6670] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6673] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6681] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6845] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm0]: failed to connect modem: Only IPv4 is supported by this modem
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6846] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <warn>  [1726645471.6850] device (cdc-wdm0): Activation: failed for connection 'huawei-4g'
set 18 04:44:31 dell-inspiron-15-3520 NetworkManager[797]: <info>  [1726645471.6852] device (cdc-wdm0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Also, the modem sometimes opens a storage device in Debian with the windows .exe drivers. Apart from that the modem is still visible through modem manager and lsusb.
Do anyone knows what is going on and how to make a GSM/cellular connection work in this Debian GNU/Linux?

Huawei E5372 is supposed to work without user installable drivers simply by emulating and Ethernet connection over USB, everything else being managed in its internal web server. Customer reviews at Amazon confirm this. Some also mention its MicroSD reader, i.e., another "plug'n'play" feature. Have you by any chance use usb_modeswitch at some point? Again, you're aren't supposed to, you're supposed to just connect it, wait for a new Ethernet connection to show up and then simply open your browser at the gateway address and manage everything from there.

I haven't used or activated usb_modeswitch manually but I know it is already installed on my Debian 12. When plugging the device via USB it indeed creates an interface named "wwx0c5b8f279a64" but no connection or IP is given to it.
When on Windows it indeed automatically creates a new interface and a network where the modem is in 192.168.8.1 and a DHCP server serves IPs in the 192.168.8.0/24 range.

It should behave exactly the same way in Debian.

That's weird because I'v just installed Debian 12, meaning it's a clean installation without other softwares that could interfere. I'v tried using it on pfSense and had no luck with it too.
